# how can i select mixed number using notepad++ regular expression

Tags: regex, numbers, notepad++

I have some number like:

```
1 , 2|1 , 3|2 , 3|1, 2 , 3
```

**or**

```
1,2,3|1,4|1,2,4|2,4|1,2,3,4
```

**or**

```
1 , 2|1 , 3|2 , 3|1, 2 , 3
```

I have 20k of line with string and such number.
I only want to find such number and replace it.
so How can i select such number (everything like 1 , 2|1 , 3|2 , 3|1, 2 , 3 or 1,2,3|1,4|1,2,4|2,4|1,2,3,4) or like this.

Comment: `\d+\s*(?:,\s*\d+)+(?:\|\d+\s*(?:,\s*\d+)+)+`

Answer (score 0):

To match "everything like `1 , 2|1 , 3|2 , 3|1, 2 , 3`", you can use:

```
^1\s*,\s*(2|1)\s*,\s*(3|2)\s*,\s*(3|1)\s*,\s*2\s*,\s*3$
```

To match "everything like `1,2,3|1,4|1,2,4|2,4|1,2,3,4`", you can use:

```
^1,2,(3|1),(4|1),2,(4|2),(4|1),2,3,4$
```

And replace each `,` with `\s*,\s*` again, if necessary.